# How to test that an exported resource in puppet exists after collecting?

Tags: monitoring, nagios, puppet

I want to create a nagios_hostgroup if some hosts exists. For creating hosts in nagios I am using exported resources which I collect on the monitoring server.

How can I test that a exported nagios_host resource exists? I tried the following:

```
Nagios_host <<| |>>

if defined(Nagios_host['host_1']) and defined(Nagios_host['host_2']) {
  nagios_hostgroup { 'database_servers':
    alias   => 'My Hostgroup',
    members => 'host_1,host_2',
  }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you solved that one? Having the same and I don't want use facts as they add additional run cycle.